# How do I force GitHub Enterprise to refresh gravatar?

Tags: github, gravatar

I updated the gravatar for my e-mail address (a few days ago), but GitHub Enterprise is still displaying the old one.  How do I force it to refresh?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: No change.  I've even tried using another browser.  Same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fix is easy. I will confirm this works since I work at the same organization as Brian Knoblauch. Simply navigate to ${github.url}/stafftools and navigate down to the 'enable gravatars' option (under settings tab) and enable it. The server will restart and your gravatars will now appear.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have to wait for some minutes, hours or days too for it to be updated on GitHub. But till then give this a try, go to your profile settings page https://github.com/settings/profile and change the Gravatar email at bottom (any random email) and reload the page, then put your valid email address in the input field and save, then refresh the page again.

Comment: Good thought, but still not working.  :-(

Comment: If you don't mind can you show me your public GitHub profile? I will check if it's updated or not ?

Comment: This is on a private GitHub Enterprise install.

Comment: It's okay :)

Now you can just wait and watch. It might take time to propagate the servers.